# Send Fluent-bit log streams from On-Premise K8s Cluster to AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, fluent-bit, kairosvm

I am here after 10 days of struggle to achieve this. All I need, is to send on-premise K8s cluster application logs to `AWS CloudWatch` using `Fluent-bit`.

Another thing is that I am on `KairOS VM` machine which is immutable and cannot download or install anything like any Linux/Windows machine, e.g. I cannot even perform setup for `awscli2`. In-short lot of limitations on the K8s cluster.

So, what I did? I used `fluent-bit` `helm` package to complete its installation on K8s cluster and edited the `ConfigMap` to add an `[OUTPUT]` for `cloudwatch_logs` plugin. The changes are as below.

```
[FILTER]
    Name   kubernetes
    Match  kube.*
    Kube_Tag_Prefix kube.var.log.containers.
    Kube_URL        https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
    Kube_CA_File    /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    Kube_Token_File /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

[OUTPUT]
    Name cloudwatch_logs
    Match   *
    region ap-south-1
    log_group_name /aws/my_cloudwatch_group
    log_stream_prefix from-fluent-bit-
    auto_create_group On
```

After restarting the pod, I can see the log streams are generated in the pod logs `kubectl logs`. Till here I am good.

Below are my questions where I am struggling.

1. How do I connect from on-premise k8s cluster to AWS service CloudWatch without using awscli2?

   - What I tried for this? **ANS** - I did setup for `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config` files in KairOS VM, these files store the `access_key_id`, `secret_key` and `region` (`MFA` for token is disabled in aws, so not used).
   - Note here - these files exist in local KairOS VM. The problem with this method is that when I restart the pod, the pod logs say that `[aws-credentials] the file ~/.aws/credentials does not exist`. I was surprised to see that error message.
   - Later I realized, it is expecting that credentials file to be available on the pod container. So I did `kubectl exec` into pod and created these files and surprisingly it worked. But since it's not a good idea to reveal credentials on pod itself, what is the best way to authenticate on-prem cluster to aws to achieve this? I have a default profile in these files where keys are added.

Pod logs: (*why it is looking for the credentials file in the pod container? we cannot do that.*)
[image]

2. Another way I tried to setup `AWS RolesAnywhere` using `CA certificate`, but I am unable to setup `aws_signing-helper` to add credentials. It's restricted by KairOS VM.

What is the way to connect an on-prem cluster to AWS? I have an IAM role and policy created in AWS but how do we use them with on-prem cluster?

"Sorry for lengthy question! I had to add this much to explain the problem"

Note - If you think, KairOS VM restrictions are stopping you to answer the question, please decommission it from question and think a case where a Linux machine without `awscli2` installed in it, then how to achieve all of that.  Thanks!!

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.